# Modeling Quantum Aspects with Probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, determinism

This is a question I've had a while about quantum theory.

Many times when I look at books and equations about this subject matter I see that the use many concepts in probability. (Correct me if Im wrong) Like how the movement of atom can be modeled using probability distributions. So I was wondering when physics takes this approach to this subject matter is it saying that the movement of an atom is actually random or that the details of explaining may be to cumbersome and be approximated with great accuracy just by using these distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantum world is really random. There are no [local hidden variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_variable_theory#Bell.27s_theorem).

Comment: Short, but to the point. +1 with the link.

Answer (score 0):

> So I was wondering when physics takes this approach to this subject matter is it saying that the movement of an atom is actually random or that the details of explaining may be to cumbersome and be approximated with great accuracy just by using these distributions?

Depends on the physicist. Some like to think there is fundamental randomness in nature, some think that unpredictability is due to our poor knowledge. It is hard to prove one or either point of view right.

This is an old argument that is not necessarily associated with quantum theory only. Similar problems plague theory of probability.